# Limiting MySQL result to one if results match

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a blog, and I'm working on a tag system, where the poster can add tags to their posts. The tags are separated by space, and will be displayed on the frontpage for visitors to browse posts by tags. I'm using explode to separate tags in each posts tag field, but I've run into a problem.

Right now, I'm able to list all tags separately. I'm listing them in a `ul` list, but what happens is that each post's tags are displayed in a separate `ul`, and not in one `ul` for all tags from all posts. So what I'm trying to do is to only show one tag if there exist more of it, so if more than one post has used PHP as a tag, the list on the frontpage will only show PHP once. How is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?php
        $query="SELECT post_tags FROM post";
        $post_tags=mysql_query($query);
        if ($post_tags)
        {
            while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($post_tags))
            {
                $tags_string .= $row['post_tags']. " ";
            }
        }
        $tags = explode($tags_string, " ");
        $tags = array_unique($tags);
    ?>
```

Comment: thanks a lot for taking the time to help me out, really! but i can't seem to find out how to echo or print out the tags in a list, could you help me?

Comment: <table>
<?php
if(sizeof($tags) > 0)
for($counter = 0; $counter < sizeof($tags); $counter++)
{
 ?>
 <tr><td><?php echo $tags[$counter]; ?></td></tr>
 <?php
}
?></table>

Comment: i know this might be annoying to you, and i'm sorry, but this is really hard. but after posting the code you just posted, i still can't echo out the tags.

Comment: but after posting the code you just posted, i still can't echo out the tags.  means.....

Comment: i mean testing the code you posted, it still won't be echoed out.

Comment: <table>
<?php
if(sizeof($tags) > 0)
{
for($counter = 0; $counter < sizeof($tags); $counter++)
{
 ?>
 <tr><td><?php echo $tags[$counter]; ?></td></tr>
 <?php
}
}
?></table>

Comment: <?php


 $tags[0] = "test"; 
 $tags[1] = "test2";
 $tags[2] = "test3";
?>

<table> <?php if(sizeof($tags) > 0) { for($counter = 0; $counter < sizeof($tags); $counter++) { ?> <tr><td><?php echo $tags[$counter]; ?></td></tr> <?php } } ?></table>

Comment: hmm, give me a couple of minutes, i'll try to figure it out. or could you post the whole code, maybe i've done something wrong.

Comment: the test text appears, but not the tags from the database

Comment: <?php  print_r($tags);exit; //check that  what is display ?>

Comment: it displays the test variables

Comment: <?php

    $query="SELECT post_tags FROM post";
        $post_tags=mysql_query($query);
            if($post_tags)
            {                                   
                while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($post_tags))
                    {
                    $tags_string .= $row['post_tags']. " ";
                    }           
            }
        $tags = explode($tags_string, " ");
        $tags = array_unique($tags);
print_r($tags);
?>

Comment: still not working, but i'm not going to bother you anymore, i'll try to find some other way around to create a tag system for mye blog ;) but thanks a lot for the help! :D

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT DISTINCT`

Comment: thanks for the reply, but that didn't work :( but maybe this will be more spesific: for each posts, i have a colunm called post_tags, where the tags are inserted like this: 'mysql php css html', and when i'm pulling them out to display them, i use explode and a foreach. did that make any sense? and if you got a better way to create a tag system, like the one stackoverflow has, please tell me ! :)

Comment: @Truls: That is not a very efficient way to store tags in the DB. You should create a table called tags with tag_id and tag_name, another table for all posts, and a one-to-many connection table to show which tags are relevant to each post. This way it is a bit easier to read the tags for a specific post, and A LOT easier to show 'all posts for tag X' or 'all tags for user Y'.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) function to remove duplicate values from an array.

Like this:

```
$tags=array_unique($tags);
```

Comment: With this you needlessly transfer data from database layer to application layer. In this particular case it might not be a big deal (expected result set should be small) , but in general it is not good practice.

Comment: It seems to be a good option if you store tags as comma seperated.

Comment: ok, lets say i got with that, and have tags sparated like this : 'php, mysql, html', what would the code look like? just want to mention that i'm very new to php, still a lot of functions and things i haven't learned yet ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply logic.

Your 'explode' will be repeated as many times as there are rows.

If you select each tag only once, you should get what you need

You can do this with

```
SELECT post_tags 
FROM post
GROUP BY post_tags
```

the same can be achived with

```
SELECT DISTINCT post_tags
FROM post
```

Of course you could do the same at level of the application, but then you needlessly transfer data from database layer to application layer.

**EDIT:**
(Initial answer based on wrong assumptions)
With your current design you are breaking 1NF and this has various bad effects. 
Let me list some:

- low performance when searching for all posts with certain tag
- low performance and complex queries when wanting to get number of posts under each tag, or get n most used tags
- decent speed for displaying single post

other queries will also suffer from the design decision to put multiple values in a single attribute (for example some real fun awaits if you need to rename or delete a tag, or if you manage to end up with a space in the name, etc...)

Normally you don't do this in databases, but instead you do three tables

```
Posts(PostKey)

PostsTags(PostKey,TagKey)

Tags(TagKey)
```

Then when you want to tag an entry you insert one row for each tag.

This allows to have decent speed for all of the above query scenarios - normalizing your database will generally do that - make your system perform well across a wide range of queries.

Comment: I think the problem with your implementation is that post_tags is a String like: "mysql php" or "php mysql databases". In this way there will still be duplicates.

Comment: Yup, you are right... whole answer based on wrong assumption - that the database was actually in 1NF :) (though table name should have been a hint)